# How to create a trigger that update the date and time field and modify of the row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, trigger

I want to create trigger that will update the record. The situation is like:

I have one column named `CheckInDateTime` and one more named `Status`.  If the administrator is not able to update the Status within 30 minutes of `CheckInDateTime` I want to update the `Status` column of that particular row.

How can I update that particular row?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "if administrator not able to update the Status after half hour of checkintime. then I want to update the column of that perticular row" - it is unclear what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I will tell  you exact what I'm want to do, If first time  status field has value PendingForApproval. If admin is not able to approve that perticular record within 30 min, then i want to update that perticular record's value to be ForcefullyClosed. How can I do ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: MsSqlServer 2008

Comment: You dont need a trigger for this. As Max pointed out, you have to use sql agent to schedule it.

Comment: Not only do you not *need* a trigger for this, a trigger would be an incredibly ill-advised solution here. I just had a brief nightmare of someone putting a WAITFOR inside of a trigger. Just in case someone reads this thread and thinks "Well, he didn't need a trigger but he *could* have used one", let me be clear: Triggers are for doing *instantaneous* operations against the data Inserted and/or Deleted; they are not for anything that involves waiting or scheduling. Down that road lies the path to performance hell.

Answer (score 1):

Create a task in SQL Server Agent that runs a stored procedure once every minute that updates the affected rows.

For instance, something like this might work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRows
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Cutoff DATETIME;
    SET @Cutoff = DATEADD(mi, -30, GETDATE());
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET Status = 'ForcefullyClosed'
    WHERE CheckInDateTime < @Cutoff AND Status IS NULL;
END;
```